# How to find specific data in nested object structure in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I shared a piece of code which demonstrate I have two types of `response`. If you take a look at the code below you will find out the `response` of a service result would be slightly different. In the first type, you have a single `data` but in the second one, this `data` has another `data` in itself.

```json
{
    "data": {
        "hasError": false,
        "developerMessage": null,
        "totalCount": 43
    },
    "hasError": false,
    "developerMessage": null
}
```

Or:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "hasError": false,
        "developerMessage": null,
        "data": {
            "hasError": false,
            "developerMessage": null,
            "totalCount": 43
        },
        "totalCount": 43
    },
    "hasError": false,
    "developerMessage": null
}
```

So to handle this predicament I had to first check the result of `response` and split it into two blocks. The big problem is that for reasons I can't explain here, this hierarchy might expand and I have three data, but what we're sure of is that the `data` in the `response` is always **the deepest**. (The *third* item in this example)

```js
   return this.httpWrapperService.get(url + tableNameWithSlash, {
            params: params, additionalOptions: {spinnerEnabled: false}
          }).then((result: any) => {

            if (result.data.data) {
              // code
              return [...result.data.data];
            } 

            else if (result.data) {
              // code
              return [...result.data];
            }

          });
```

I was wondering if there is a better solution to handle this dynamic `response`.

Comment: I think it's a sign that the overall architecture needs to be looked at if you're planning on nesting data like that. Are you able to return everything in a data array and give each object a property that references its parent?

Comment: This issue comes from the hierarchy model and there is no choice but to find the deepest data.

Comment: Are you concerned about strongly typing your function or are you satisfied with the "any" type?

Comment: The array spread seems wrong, all your `data` properties have objects as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursion to make a solution that works for any depth, e.g. data being on the 4th layer

```
    .then((result: any) => {
        const findData = (response: any) => {
           return response.data ? findData(response.data):response;
        }
         return [...findData(result.data)];

          });
```

Comment: You should test for the existence of `response.data` as the base case, not `response.data.data`

Comment: If you know there's at least one level of nesting, rather call `findData(result.data)`

Comment: Good point, updated my answer